# Toggling a background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, background

My brain is going round in circles trying to figure this out - I think I need the help of someone with a bigger brain! Admittedly I'm a jQuery novice so I'm hoping the solution to my problem is fairly simple. I'm trying to write some code that will toggle the background image of a div (which has already been specified by a stylesheet to introduce a :hover function). The div's that I'm affecting also function to toggle other div's in a question/answer situation.

At present, I've managed to get to the stage (with the following code) that the jQuery DOES change the background image as intended (in this case, from green '/img/bg/nav-giclee.png' to black '/img/bg/nav-down.png');

HOWEVER what I need is for only one of the divs to be black at any one time, ie when selected. At the moment after being clicked and turning to black, the div remains black even when an alternative DIV is clicked. I suppose what I'm aiming for is for clicking on a DIV to reset the background images of the other DIVs (whilst not interfering with their show/hide question/answer features). Have I overcomplicated this explanation?!?

The working page is at: http://sketch360test.co.uk/giclee.php/... Many thanks in advance for any benevolent help...

The jquery I'm using for now is:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};

$(function() {
    $("#answer .views-row").hide();
    $("#question .views-row").click(function(){
        var i = $(this).index();
        $("#answer .views-row").eq(i).toggle("slow").siblings().hide();
        $(".question").eq(i).css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-down.png)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#answer .views-row").hide();
    $("#question .views-row").click(function(){
        var i = $(this).index();
        $("#answer .views-row").eq(i).toggle("slow").siblings().hide();
        $(".question").css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-giclee.png)").eq(i).css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-down.png)");
    });
});
```

Also, I would recommend adding / removing a CSS class rather then setting `background-image` manually - you may find out than you have to modify more properties, ie. border.

UPDATE

```
$(".question").removeClass("selected").eq(i).addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Hi @Jakub Konecki thanks for your response - I tried all of the solutions and yours worked straight away! Thankyou. However, I agree with your suggestion of adding/removing a CSS class rather than setting background-image on it's own (some of the other solutions on this page also suggested it). Could you please describe how to amend your line below to affect the css class instead? 
        $(".question").css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-giclee.png)").eq(i).css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-down.png)");

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks again. I've come across a new difficulty that I wasn't expecting - getting another element to trigger the same 'answer' boxes as the 'question' buttons do... ie if you look at the page http://www.sketch360test.co.uk/giclee.php ...and click on 'Giclee - the process', I have a picture in there "Pick your Paper", which I would like to toggle the 'answer' div which is currently triggered by the 'the papers' button.  I've tried to do this myself (the code is in /js/fiddle.js) but although I can get the 'answer' div to toggle, it won't bring up the correct 'answer' panel.

Comment: i think i've found a way of doing it now although what i've done is probably VERY messy!

Comment: hmm, it seems my 'solution' doesn't work in ie7 / 8 ... if you had any ideas Jakub I would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: thanks again @Jakub Konecki. I've come across a new difficulty that I wasn't expecting - getting another element to trigger the same 'answer' boxes as the 'question' buttons do... ie if you look at the page sketch360test.co.uk/giclee.php ...and click on 'Giclee - the process', I have a picture in there "Pick your Paper", which I would like to toggle the 'answer' div which is currently triggered by the 'the papers' button. I've tried to do this myself (the code is in /js/fiddle.js) but although I can get the 'answer' div to toggle, it won't bring up the correct 'answer' panel.

Answer (score 1):

It would be healthy to use css class to apply background image instead of hardcoding that in javascript. And just remove this class from other divs while applying to currently being clicked.

```
$(".view-row").removeClass("backgroundDown");
$(".view-row").eq(i).addClass("backgroundDown");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should reset the current one.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .backgroundDown {
        background-image: url(/img/bg/nav-down.png);
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    $(function() {
    $("#answer .views-row").hide();
    $("#question .views-row").click(function(){
        var i = $(this).index();
        $("#answer .views-row").eq(i).toggle("slow").siblings().hide();
        //$(".question").eq(i).css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-down.png)");
        $(".question .backgroundDown").removeClass("backgroundDown");
        $(".question").eq(i).addClass("backgroundDown");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'reseting' all of the divs backgrounds to the original, and then setting the clicked one's to black

```
$(function() {
    $("#answer .views-row").hide();

    var views_row = $("#question .views-row");
    views_row.click(function(){
        var i = $(this).index();
        $("#answer .views-row").eq(i).toggle("slow").siblings().hide();

        // Add this line...
        views_row.css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-giclee.png)");
        $(".question").eq(i).css("background-image", "url(/img/bg/nav-down.png)");
    });
});
```